# How long must I wait before quitting after returning from an overseas assignment?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, quitting, international

I'm returning to my home country after a 2 year overseas placement. Is there a certain amount of time that I should stay from the perspective of professional integrity?

More details: I'm working on integrating two products and I came here to get to know the people and the code to continue the integration after I return. I have been with the company for eight years and it seems like I owe it to them to stick around a bit after the investment they made in me.

Comment: Why do you think it will look bad? End of the placement - perhaps it is one of the best times to move on before they put you into the middle of another big project

Comment: I've edited the title to match your question but your core questions is awfully broad. Apparently we don't have a general "How much notice should I give?" question though.

Comment: I edited it back.  The question was really meant to be about how long should I stick around before looking for another job, not the notification period.

Comment: I'm confused about the question. Was this overseas placement a thing your company did because you asked that they do so in order to keep you as a worker, or was this a situation where the company asked you to move overseas for 2 years as part of your job?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there is no timeframe like that that would impact on your integrity. It would pose some inconvenience to the company perhaps, but thats not something that is professionally wrong. Any employee leaving poses inconvenience.

If anything this is a good time to leave for the company because you have just finished your OS placement and have not yet got your teeth into something else. It would be even worse for them if you left halfway through something.

Comment: The only caveat I can see is if you signed something promising to stay for X amount of time if given this opportunity - something companies do for long term, expensive training sometimes  (and I suppose an overseas assignment could fall into this category). Then you would need to stay for that amount of time that you contractually obligated yourself to stay or payback the costs as provided in the agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment the question is about when to start job hunting not how much notice to give.

The only point that you may owe your company more than your notice period is the first year of your employment with them.  Beyond that your notice period is how long you should stick around.  You should always be looking for another job.